# XCode 6 issue - dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier not returning custom cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a UITableViewController with 2 prototype cells with custom heights - one has a height of 187 points and the other has a height of 140 points.  The tableview's default row height is ser to 187.

My cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        MyListingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyListingCell"];
        [cell initWithListing:[self.listings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return cell;
    } else {
        return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddMyListingCell"];
    }
}
```

and I have a matching heightForRowAtIndexPath which looks like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyListingCell"];
        return cell.frame.size.height;
    } else {

        //if no listings exist, make the cell full-screen height
        if (self.listings.count == 0) {   
            return tableView.frame.size.height;
        } else {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddMyListingCell"];
            return cell.frame.size.height;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the cell heights come out correctly.  187 and 140 respectively.

However, I would like to change the size of the larger cell to 213 points.  To do this I change the custom tablecell height to 213.  The problem is that when I run the code (using XCode 6) the table cells still come out as height 187.

I tried changing the default tableview rowheight property, also to 213.  However I still get 187.  In fact, when I look at the storyboard (as text) there is no mention of 187 anywhere.  But it seems that XCode is remembering the previous value.

I have tried cleaning, deep cleaning, restarting xcode, deleteing the app from my phone, and deleting my debug products.  I can't get it to forget the 187.

**Could this be a bug in XCode 6?**  In XCode 5 this does not happen (proven). Custom cell heights have been working fine in XCode 5 but this problem has arisen the very day after I install XCode 6.

Can anyone help with some advice on things to try, or some confirmation that I'm not going crazy.

Comment: This looks like an issue having to do with how cells are made and their heights dealt with, rather than Xcode. If I recall correctly, heightForRowAtIndexPath is called BEFORE the cell is created, not after.

Comment: @theDuncs - Curious if you have had any luck in resolving this issue? I believe I have encountered the same thing - I am attempting to use two prototype cells in a UITableView each with a different row height. At first I had looked into the heightForRowAtIndexPath: method but have not had any success in using this with iOS8. Did you happen to find a way to accomplish this using the Storyboard Table View Cell custom row height? Thanks!

Comment: @DerekLee I filed a radar with Apple and they said that it was a problem that was already reported.   I have found no other workaround yet, except to copy a UITableViewCell from a pre XCode6 storyboard, paste it in, and amend the three size parameters in the storyboard xml file. Let me know if you want me to post that as a possible workaround.

Comment: @theDuncs At least that suggestion fixed it for me. I copy pasted a cell that was created in Xcode 5. Problem solved. Thank you very much. Hope Apple will fix this soon.

Answer (score 1):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called BEFORE `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so you can never use it to try to reference a cell and get the height. Look at the following code with the following log lines and result:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"CELL");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"HEIGHT");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell);
    return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

That results in:

```
2014-09-23 09:55:05.114 NewTesting[54040:60b] HEIGHT
2014-09-23 09:55:05.114 NewTesting[54040:60b] (null)
2014-09-23 09:55:05.115 NewTesting[54040:60b] HEIGHT
2014-09-23 09:55:05.115 NewTesting[54040:60b] (null)
2014-09-23 09:55:05.115 NewTesting[54040:60b] HEIGHT
2014-09-23 09:55:05.116 NewTesting[54040:60b] (null)
2014-09-23 09:55:05.116 NewTesting[54040:60b] HEIGHT
2014-09-23 09:55:05.116 NewTesting[54040:60b] (null)
2014-09-23 09:55:05.117 NewTesting[54040:60b] CELL
2014-09-23 09:55:05.118 NewTesting[54040:60b] CELL
2014-09-23 09:55:05.119 NewTesting[54040:60b] CELL
2014-09-23 09:55:05.120 NewTesting[54040:60b] CELL
```

With that in mind the method you're using would never work.

Have you tried something more simple, like the following (although I would personally use constants)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return indexPath.section == 0 ? 213 : 140;
}
```

That is assuming all the cells in the first section are 213 tall and any other section 140 tall, which may be incorrect.

Ultimately, I think the best way to do what you want to do is to essentially ask your data source what type of cell should exist at that given `indexPath`, and therefore how tall the cell should be.

Comment: I've been using heightForRowAtIndexPath for months without problem.  It correctly pulls down the custom height of the cell, where the cell is defined in the storyboard.  In your example I'm assuming you haven't added a UITableViewCell to your stroyboard with a reuse identifier of "cell". If you do that, it should return the right values.

Comment: That is correct, I'm not using (and generally don't use) storyboards. But as I said in my answer, why not just return the heights you know they will be based on the data source and section? That way you don't even have to mess with trying to dequeue cells (potentially) before they exist. I would be extremely surprised if using storyboards changes the order of operations.

Comment: Because I don't want to hardcode the height of the cells into the code. I want to be able to change the height of the cells in storyboard and for the change to be reflected in the app.  This is functionality which has been working fine in XCode 5 for the last year.

Comment: While I understand where you're coming from, you're "hard-coding" the height either way, one in the code, one in the storyboard. I don't understand *how* it would have worked, because as I said heightForRow is called before cellForRow, so the cells haven't been initialized yet, and thus dequeuing cells should't work. AFAIK this is the case even if the cells are created using storyboards, but I absolutely could be wrong. Do you still have Xcode 5?

Comment: You're absolutely are wrong, Mike.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Any chance you still have Xcode 5 hanging around? I would be very interested to know what you get when you add the NSLog lines as I did above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61765/discussion-between-theduncs-and-mike).

Comment: @OrShanoon - no solution yet.  :(

Comment: @simpleBob - no solution yet.  :(

Comment: I did as you said, in the code area height For Row AtIndexPath, I return indexPath.section = 300 ,and I set the custom cell heigt custom 200,in the storyboard, I run the app, it finally shows 200 , and when i deleted the func of  heightForRowAtIndexPath, then run the app ,it finally shows 44,  I really confused me